# Resave Wordpress custom post types in code

Tags: wordpress

In my Wordpress website I have about 250 posts (for a particular custom post type)

I have created a boolean custom field (using Advanced Custom Field plugin) that defaults to true; however, this custom field does not have any value unless I manually open the post and just hit publish to save the post.

Doing this for 250 posts is very time consuming.

Is it possible I can iterate through all my custom posts and just "save" them on function.php file (without changing anything)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to do it the one time, you could write a loop to iterate through all of your CPT's, then dump that into a template file, go to a page that uses that template, and remove the data once it's changed. It tried this by adding this code to the page.php template file of my theme.

```
<?php 
   $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_NAME',
    );

    $posts_array = get_posts($args);

    foreach ($posts_array as $post_val) {
        update_field( 'ACF_FIELD_NAME_HERE', true , $post_val->ID);
    }
?>
```

Remember to delete that code when done.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is posible. If i'm not wrong ACF save the values in wp_postmeta table, knowing this, you can use the hook `save_post` to create a loop across all your posts and save the custom value related to each post.

Obviously only saving just one post.

Now, Create a funcion with the `save_post` hook in your function.php

```
function saveMetabox(){
  global $wpdb;

  //Your query to get all the posts ids from wp_posts...
  $ids = $wpdb->get_results('....');

  //your loop to insert values in wp_postmeta...
  foreach($ids as $id){
    add_post_meta($id->ID, 'ACF_Key', 'The value');
  }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'saveMetabox' );
```

Once you save the first post, **remove this function from function.php**

Read more of [add post meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) and [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

**REMEMBER BACKUP YOUR DB FIRST**